# Htaccess redirect happens different for www and non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have redirected all non www to www url using the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Next , 
The final url for categories required is :

```
http://www.slidecorner.com/category/Design
```

I have used this for achieving this

```
RewriteRule ^/?category/(.*) category.php?ctitle=$1
```

This also works, but when i check this url in any redirect checking websites , the "www" version of url is perfect, but "non www" url internally redirects to :

```
http://www.slidecorner.com/category.php/Design?ctitle=Design
```

Is this good for a search engine ? Please advise

Update : Tried [L] flag also , and rewritebase is already there. Attached full htaccess for reference

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^docs$ docs.php
RewriteRule ^category$ category.php
RewriteRule ^categories$ categories.php
RewriteRule ^members$ members.php
RewriteRule ^upload$ upload.php
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php
RewriteRule ^account$ account.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php
RewriteRule ^feeds$ feeds.php
RewriteRule ^mydocs$ mydocs.php
RewriteRule ^myfav$ myfavoritedocs.php

RewriteRule ^doc/(.*)/(.*) viewdoc.php?did=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^syndicate/docs/(.*)/(.*) syndicatedocs.php?filter=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^download/doc/(.*)/(.*) downloaddoc.php?DID=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^resetpassword/(.*) resetpassword.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^confirmemail/(.*) confirmemail.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^resendconfirmation/(.*) resendconfirmation.php?userid=$1
RewriteRule ^members/profile/(.*)/(.*) memberprofile.php?pid=$1&username=$2

RewriteRule ^/?category/(.*) category.php?ctitle=$1 [L]



# to hide jpg images
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.com[NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg)$ - [F]
# to hide jpg images


# for sending compressed data to load faster
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# for sending compressed data to load faster


</IfModule>



# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#non www redirect ,since the above doesnt redirect 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##



<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>


Options -Indexes
```

Update :  I found the issue is due to this code

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I removed that and the url is fine . Also the non www to www redirection is completely stopped because i removed that

Is there anything wrong with the above code ?

Comment: edit with your question changes

Comment: update: Done corrections in the questions

Comment: checked puting the non www in address bar of browser ?geting right location?

Comment: When i put non www version it redirects to http://www.slidecorner.com/category.php/Design?ctitle=Design

Comment: The "redirect checking website" maybe wrong (TBH I've not found one that is without bugs). However, if you are using relative path substitutions then you must also use the `RewriteBase` directive OR make your substitution root-relative (or absolute). `L` flag required? If you have the canonical `www` at the start of your .htaccess file then it's impossible for there to be any difference between the `www` and non-`www` versions with respect to this internal rewrite.

Comment: Your question implies you are doing the external redirection first, however,  your code dump shows otherwise. Generally, external redirects should come before internal rewrites. The canonical `www` redirection should be the first thing in your .htaccess file. Not related, but you also have another error in your .htaccess file: `slidecorner.com[NC]` - there should be a space before `[NC]` (are you sure you need the `NC` flag here?)

Comment: Hey w3d , that worked like a charm. I moved the www redirection to the top ,and it worked.  I am a newbie in htaccess, did not know that. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of directives (within modules) matters in .htaccess. Whilst your question suggests you are performing the canonical `www` redirect first, you actually have this *after* the internal rewrites in your .htaccess files and this is certainly a problem in this case. (Although the exact output you are getting from the "checking tool/website" would seem to be a fault of the "tool" IMO.)

Generally, you should always have external redirects *before* internal rewrites.

With the internal rewrite first you ending up *losing* your "pretty URL". What actually happens when you access the non-canonical (non-`www`) URL `http://example.com/category/Design` is:

1. Internal rewrite to:
   `/category.php?ctitle=Design`
2. External redirect to:
   `http://www.example.com/category.php?ctitle=Design`

It is important to realise that the `L` (`last`) flag only halts the current processing of the rule set. If an internal or external redirect has occurred then process starts again!